# Listview's item position 0 hold another listview with 10 items which each item open single activity but different text data

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-listview

Please check pics first if don't get understood my question yet.

**first listview position** **0** holds the **second listview having 10 items** which all open a single activity but show different text data according to the listview item is clicked from **10 items**.

**Example**, first listview position 0 opens and **display the second listview** then *second listview position 0* is clicked, opens an activity with text data in textview. **Now second activity position 1 is opened and open the same activity but the date is changed.**

***I don't want to make 10 different activity*** .

I tried "put and getextra" but didn't get proper results to what I want.

First list view

[image: first_list]

Second list view

[image: second_list]

```
ArrayList<MenuItems> items = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList<MenuItems> task2Item = new ArrayList<>();

//================= First Listview==========
items.add(new MenuItems("Task 1", "Solved graphs"));

items.add(new MenuItems("Voca bulary 1", "Vocabulary related task 1, Structures"));

items.add(new MenuItems("Connectors 1 ", "How to start Essay Task 1, body-paragraph "));


items.add(new MenuItems("Task 2", "Solved essay "));

items.add(new MenuItems("Vocabulary 2", "Vocabulary related task 2, Structures"));

items.add(new MenuItems("Connectors 2 ", "How to start Essay Task 2, body-paragraphs "));


items.add(new MenuItems("Collocation", "Important thing to get high score"));

items.add(new MenuItems("Tips & Tricks", "Best Solutions"));


=========================================================

// listview which is inside first list view 's items ================================================================
task2Item.add(new MenuItems("Crime","This essay about crime"));
task2Item.add(new MenuItems("Education","This essay about Education"));
task2Item.add(new MenuItems("University","This essay about University"));
task2Item.add(new MenuItems("Food","This essay about Food"));
task2Item.add(new MenuItems("Games","This essay about crime"));
task2Item.add(new MenuItems("Experience","This essay about crime"));
task2Item.add(new MenuItems("This is another essay","This essay about crime"));
task2Item.add(new MenuItems("This is another essay","This essay about crime"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your desired object as parcelable and Pass Object array as argument like this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),YourActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("data", Objects);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then you can get this arrayList as follows:

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    Objects = bundle.getParcelable("data");
```

Comment: can i pass data in different Textviews? the layout is going to have  5 textview. one for title, intro and paragraphs and thanks for answering

Comment: and can u suggest me more topics that I should cover related Android and data